# Trouble getting to Angular app after logging in on non Angular page

Tags: javascript, angular, protractor

I’m trying to create a simple test where I click on a button in my Angular app.  However, when I navigate to my Angular app it first redirects me to a non Angular login page.

So a user’s experience is as follows:  The user navigates to https://test.com and then is redirected to a login page where they enter a username and password and click the Submit button.  Then the app page loads which contains a button which they can click.

I’ve got my code working to the point where when I run protractor, I see a chrome window open, I see the login page appear and I can see text filling into both the ‘Username’ and ‘Password’ fields.  However, right after that the chrome browser closes.  I do not see my app page loads which contains the button I want to click.

The code I’m using to try and login is as follows (NOTE: username and password text were changed to something fake so I could post my question)

```
describe('Go to Test site', function() {
  it('and login', function() {
    browser.get('https://test.com');
    browser.ignoreSynchronization=true;
     element(by.name('login')).sendKeys('username');
     element(by.id('cred_password_inputtext')).sendKeys('password');
     element(by.id('cred_sign_in_button')).click();
     //browser.ignoreSynchronization=false;
  });
});
```

What is the next step?  Should I be using “browser.ignoreSynchronization=false;”?  Do I need to find the button element on the next page?

At this point I would be happy just to see my app page load so I can even see the button in the test browser.  It closes so fast. This is my first question so I apologize if it's confusing.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by @Batajus you don't have any code, so the test execution has finished.

If you only need to logon once you can place the code in a `beforeAll()` and even make a method for it that holds all the logon logic, something like this

```js
function logon(username, password) {
  var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;

  browser.get('https://test.contracts365.com');
  browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;

  // Wait for the url to be changed to the logon page
  browser.wait(EC.urlContains('login.microsoftonline.com'), 5000);

  // Do the logon magic
  element(by.name('login')).sendKeys(username);
  element(by.id('cred_password_inputtext')).sendKeys(password);
  element(by.id('cred_sign_in_button')).click();
  browser.ignoreSynchronization = false;

  // Wait till you are back on the page
  browser.wait(EC.urlContains('test.contracts365.com'), 5000);
}

describe('Go to Test site', function() {
  beforeAll(function() {
    logon('john@doe.com', 'Welcome123')
  });

  it('should do some tests', function() {
    // do some tests
  });
});
```

And then add your tests

Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you, your answer was very helpful and solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

your browser closes, because the test execution has finished. So your next step is to find a button or another element on your next loaded page.

I recommend to use `browser.wait(...)` methods with [Expected Conditions](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorExpectedConditions) to wait until your next page is fully loaded and your elements become interactable.

I hope this solves your problems, otherwise please tell me so i provide another solution ;-)

Comment: Thank you.  You are correct I did need another test to find an element on the next page.